# How to make a mobile UI automatically open per specific width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, mobile, interface

Sorry if this question was worded poorly. I didn't know how else to compress it.

I have a music player that has a button you click to toggle a smaller UI of the player, suitable for mobile. How can I set it so that the smaller player automatically opens for specific min and max height set?

- The class for the toggle is '.more'
- The smaller version is '.m-ui'
- and the div ID it's in is '#box'

if that further helps any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with the `resize` event :

I give you a little example :

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  if ($(document).width() < 500) {
    $("#player").width(50);
    $("#player").height(50);
  } else {
    $("#player").width(100);
    $("#player").height(100);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50mc23nx/

**EDIT** : with your comments I think you need to toggle class when the site opens (if you search a good way to detect if it's a mobile or not I suggest you to search on SO)

```
$(function() {
  if ($(document).width() < 500) {
    $("#box").toggleClass("m-ui", true);

  } else {
    $("#box").toggleClass("m-ui", false);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z67dtnxm/

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. 

http://imgur.com/a/xyhDH

Take a look at that image. On the left side is the full music player. On the right side is the small player. You can toggle between both interfaces by clicking the button on the top right corner.

What I want is for the small player (instead of the big one) to automatically open when the person is using a mobile.

Comment: Its easy so on the document ready check if the user is on mobile(by checking clientWidth) and then switch classes depending on the result I ll update my answer.

Comment: Hey looks like that didn't work for some reason, but using ($(window) instead of ($(document) worked! Should this be okay for what i'm trying to accomplish? I read a bit on the difference between the two but I know little to nothing about jquery so it's not easy trying to comprehend it all. Please let me know. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: window.width is the size of the browser and document.width is the size of the content, you can check this example : http://jsfiddle.net/Xme7y/1/ . Happy to help, have a good day !